# webdriver.io async issues - clicking on an element and then entering text

Tags: javascript, selenium, promise, webdriver-io

I am trying to account for "chosen selects" in my automated testing script. I am using webdriver.io and referring to the follow API info: 
http://webdriver.io/api.html

I need to click on 'a.chosen-single' which in the "chosen" world is equal to a user clicking into the select. This focuses the user on a text input (which allows the user to filter through the select options, thus why chosen is cool) and I need to then simulate the user entering the text.

The problem is that the script I wrote results in all chosen-selects being clicked and THEN the keys get entered. This means that they text is only getting entered into the final chosen-select input.

I've inserted a pause() after the element is clicked into. I would expect the pause to happen after each click, but instead the pause only happens at the end when the last element is clicked and the keys for all elements are all typed together at the end so that the last element has a value of 'FIL12'

```
this.click(container + ' a.chosen-single').then(function(){
                console.log('clicked');
                console.log('value', fields[selectName]);
                this.pause(1000)
                this.keys(fields[selectName])
                //press enter to finalize selection
                //.keys('\uE007')

                console.log('keys pressed');
              });
```

Here is the read-out I get in the terminal:

```
clicked
value F
keys pressed
clicked
value IL
keys pressed
clicked
value 1
keys pressed
clicked
value 2
keys pressed
```

I can't figure out how to assure that the next task does not get queued until the keystrokes have been entered. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`pause` its self returns a promise, so you should call `then` on `pause` to execute the block *after* the `pause` callback has returned.

```
this.pause(1000).then(function() {
  this.keys(fields[selectName])
  //press enter to finalize selection
  //.keys('\uE007')

  console.log('keys pressed');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right about pause returning a promise. However, I still haven't solved my problem. I'm working on it and will update my question once I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I finally answered my own question. The problem was that I was using a for(){} loop to iterate through different fields that I wanted filled in. The for(){} loop was executing each command without waiting for a given chosen select to finish being set with the correct value (click on select, type value, press enter). I solved this by gathering the selector and value, storing these in a function and adding each complete function to a queue. I then executed each function one at a time, calling the next function in the "then" callback of the 'keys' command within the function before (Thus calling the next function after the enter key was pressed on the proceeding chosen select). I used an iterator to grab each next function in the queue. Anyone interested can check my code and comment with any questions for suggestions. thanks!

```
webdriverio = require('webdriverio');

var tester = {};

var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
};

var params = {
  //editing this out because info is private
};

//changing the fields because info is private
var fields = {
testField: 'John Smith', 
testSelect: 'USA'

};

var execQueue = [];


var wrapFunction = function(fn, context, params) {
    return function() {
        fn.apply(context, params);
    };
};



function fillFields(driver, fields){
driver.iter = 0;
  driver.elements('select + .chosen-container').then(function(result){
    console.log('how many selects', result.value.length);
    tester.totalSelects = result.value.length;
  });

  //loop through all selects and inputs
 for(property in fields){
    var p = property;
    //closure to preserve value of property
    (function(p){
      //if chosen input then choose from list
     driver.isExisting('div.' + p + ' .chosen-results').then(function(result){

       if(result === true){

        driver.elements('div.' + p + ' select').then(function(result){
          //loop through each select (expiration date has two selections in one container)
          for(var i=0;i<result.value.length;i++){
            var s = result.value[i].ELEMENT;

            //closure
            (function(s){

            //find the name of each select
            driver.elementIdAttribute(s,'name').then(function(result){
              //find the chosen container after select
              var container = 'select[name=' + result.value + '] + .chosen-container';

              var selectName = result.value;
              //find corresponding a.chosen-single

              //this.debug()
              //click on a.chosen-single to activate chosen drop

              var qfunction = function(link, value){
                console.log('#################in qu function ###########', value);
                driver.click(link).then(function(){
                      this.keys([value, '\uE007']).then(function(){
                       driver.iter++;
                        execQueue[driver.iter]();
                      });//end keys.then


                });//end click.then
              }//end qfunction



              execQueue.push(wrapFunction(qfunction, this, [container + ' a.chosen-single', fields[selectName]]));//end push


             if(execQueue.length == tester.totalSelects - 1){
              console.log('**********equal');

                  execQueue[driver.iter]();
              }//end if equal


              console.log('queue so far', execQueue.length);


            });//end elementIdAttribute


            })(s);//end closure



          }//end for selects in container



        });//end driver.elements




        }else{

         driver.addValue('input[name=' + p + ']', fields[p]);


        }

      })//end driver.isExisting


    })(p);




  }//end for each field


};//end fillFields



webdriverio
  .remote(options)
  .init()
  .url('https://' + params.domain + '/' + params.clientId + '/?scope=' + params.scope +  '&cart=' + params.cart + '&cfg=' + params.cfg + '&progress=' + params.progress + '&language=' + params.language + '&currencyId=' + params.currencyId + '&debug=nocache') 
  .then(function(result) {

    fillFields(this, fields);

  });
```